# using javaFx table view to display the content of a selected row

Tags: java, swing, javafx, javafx-2

i have a javafx table whereby, i will want to display the content of any row that's being clicked on a different form.
below is the method i tried using, which isn't giving the expected response, although in my SceneBuilder, i added this method to the MouseClicked event.

```
public void selectedRow() throws SQLException{
        int row = studentTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        String sql = "select * from student where id= '" + row + "'";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                String add1 = rs.getString("school_name");
                System.out.println("The selected row is ==> "+ add1);
            }
    }
```

Note: I have once tried something like this using Jframe which gave me the expected response, in my Jframe...this is the method that was used in getting the job done.

```
private void all_storesMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        try {
            int row = studentTable.getSelectedRow();
            String stores_click = (studentTable.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0)).toString();
            String sql = "select * from student where id= '" + stores_click + "'";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                String add1 = rs.getString("school_name");
                System.out.println("The selected row is ==> "+ add1);
            }
    }
```

I will appreciate how to go about this please.
Thanks so much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need to do is just to make use of the split method to get the index of the row you selected, and what do i mean by this.

```
String values = String.valueOf(studentTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
String row = values.toString().split(",")[0].substring(1);
```

so, in the function you have above there, a little tweak below will get the job done for you.

```
public void selectedRow() throws SQLException{
        String values = 
        String.valueOf(studentTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        String row = values.toString().split(",")[0].substring(1);
        String sql = "select * from student where id= '" + row + "'";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                String add1 = rs.getString("school_name");
                System.out.println("The selected row is ==> "+ add1);
            }
    }
```

I hope you get what i explained up there.